# HTML validation :document type does not allow element

Tags: html, validation

It has been an hour since I started finding a solution but so far no luck. I am sure that it is just a matter of some missing tag or something but despite my efforts unable to find the issue. The page is located at:
[http://contestlancer.com/greenFields/?page_id=47](https://web.archive.org/web/20131019155534/http://contestlancer.com/greenFields/?page_id=47)
and I am getting 114 validation errors all same as title of the thread on all `<p>  and <h2>` tags in the document.

Here is the validation results link: [CLick here](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://contestlancer.com/greenFields/?page_id=47&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)
And here is a JS fiddle containing HTML Code:

[http://jsfiddle.net/fz6m6/](https://jsfiddle.net/fz6m6/)

Comment: If your are not able to find the position of an error, then you should check the “Show Source” option in the validator – that will link each error message with the position in the source code displayed further down the page, so that you can directly see what it is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` elements may not contain `<div>` elements (or indeed any block-level element).

Comment: Everywhere, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (at least) that you had `p` elements that lacked a closing tag `</p>`, which is not allowed in XHTML, and the page declares an XHTML doctype.